# c# deserialize part of json

Tags: c#, json.net

Есть нижеследущий JSON

```
{
  "items": [
    {
      "name": "Book",
      "description": "",
    }
  ]
}

class ActionCollection 
{
    [JsonProperty("items")]
    public string Content { get; set; }
}
```

нужно преобразовать массив в строку при десериализации. Сейчас падает с ошибкой
*Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: [. Path 'items''*

Comment: А зачем вам такое издевательство? Почему не создать полноценную структуру для работы с этим json?

Comment: Все остальное нужно отобразитькак есть

Answer (score 0):

Кастомный конвертер создайте:

```
public class ListToStringConverter : JsonConverter {
    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer) {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer) {
        JArray data = serializer.Deserialize<JArray>(reader);

        // тут что-то делаем, преобразуем в строку, например
        return data.ToString();
    }

    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType) {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

И в классе его назначьте:

```
internal class ActionCollection {
    [JsonProperty("items")]
    [JsonConverter(typeof (ListToStringConverter))]
    public string Content { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Т.е. в любом случае проще десериализовать, а потом уже привести к строке? Т.е. нет такого понятия десириализовать только первый уровень?

Comment: @Oleg из коробки такого нету, самому только писать.